# Extracting items in a list that are not in order

Tags: python

I want to extract some items from a list and save them in  sub-lists, but items are not in order. for example for the following list:

```
F = ['mary', 'zari', 'ali', 'fari','Thaghi', 'zagi', 'shad', 'sila','bita']
A = []
B = []
C = []
```

I want to put item 1 in A, item 2 in B, item 3 in C. Then item 4 in A, item 5 in B, item 6 in C. Then item 7 in A, 8 in B, and 9 in C. I wrote the following code:

```
i=0
for i in range(len(F)):  
    A.append(F[i])
    B.append(F[i+1])
    if i < range(len(F)): 
        i=i+1
```

But the output is:

```
A.append(F[i])
B.append(F[i+1])
     if i < range(len(F)):
         i=i+1

IndexError: list index out of range.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is that there is no `F[i+1]` when `i` reaches the end of `F`. Using list comprehensions is a better method for this problem:

```
F = ['mary', 'zari', 'ali', 'fari','Thaghi', 'zagi', 'shad', 'sila', 'bita']
A = [item for i, item in enumerate(F) if i % 3 == 0]
B = [item for i, item in enumerate(F) if i % 3 == 1]
C = [item for i, item in enumerate(F) if i % 3 == 2]
```

the result would be:

```
>>> A
['mary', 'fari', 'shad']
>>> B
['zari', 'Thaghi', 'sila']
>>> C
['ali', 'zagi', 'bita']
```

Comment: Second method doesn't properly handle cases when `F` doesn't have an exact multiple of 3 items in it.

Comment: @martineau You are right; removed that part. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Also, this could be done more concisely via `A, B, C = [[item for i, item in enumerate(F) if i % 3 == n] for n in range(3)]`.

Answer (score 3):

This will work for arbitrary lengths of `F`:

```
A, B, C = [F[i::3] for i in range(3)]
```

It makes three slices starting at indexes `0, 1, 2` respectively, each all the way to the end and each with a `step` length of `3`.

Comment: @martineau Hm. In general, I use `zip()` a lot, but here, the power of the slice should suffice. Is there anything inherently bad about `zip()?`

Comment: No, just not having to make use of it is better (more concise & faster) than needing it — and very clever.

Comment: Upvoted. You can also get rid of `len(F)`: `F[i::3]`